# Activate Virtual Environment in tmux session created by Shell file

Tags: shell, sh, virtualenv, tmux

I have written a shell script which should ideally create a tmux session and activate virtual environment in it. But it does not activate it after creating tmux session. Here is the code snippet:

```
cd /home
cd Portals/
tmux new-session -d -s devgeo 
source activate.sh
```

And this is my activate.sh file

```
source "venv/bin/activate"
```

What am I doing wrong. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing `source activate.sh` in your current shell, not in the shell running in your newly created `tmux` session. Use the `send-keys` command to send that command to the shell, as if you had typed it yourself.

```
tmux new-session -c /home/Portals -d -s devgeo
tmux send-keys -t devgeo:1 "source activate.sh" C-m
```

(The `-c` option lets you set the working directory of the new session without having to change the working directory of your current shell.)